# MySQL init script fails, but mysqld_safe works just fine?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

TLDR = /etc/init.d/mysql start fails after the follwoing line (line 22), and I would like to fix it so that init starts mysqld automatically.

Problem line:

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

Background:

This happend after I attempted to install KDE on this workstation. KDE decided to uninstall mysql-server (for some strange reason), which caused all sorts of problems including corrupt tables, which I restored from a backup.

Everything is not fixed, EXCEPT the init scripts do not work.

I narrowed it down to this line by putting "echo 'ok'" after each statement as it executes from top to bottom to see the last executing line. At first, it died because /usr/bin/mysqld_safe did not exist. apt-get remove --purge [insert all mysql packages here] followed by fixing all broken dependencies,and then apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client fixed that.

This line appears to be a line used by all init scripts, and the other init scripts execute just fine. So, I have my doubts that this is the problem. However, echoing "OK" just above this statement, and then trying to echo it just below this statement show a successful "OK" followed by nothing. So, it appears the code path ends here.